# file.open() not finding file, c++, Xcode, OpenGL

Tags: c++, xcode, file, opengl, 3d

I have tried all day at this and have found no answer that works. I am trying to load shaders in my opengl program however, the program does not seem to be able to find the files. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code

```
#include "Shader.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

static std::string loadShader(const std::string& filename);
static void checkShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const          std::string& errMessage);
static GLuint createShader(const std::string& text, GLenum shaderType);

Shader::Shader(const std::string& filename){
  m_program = glCreateProgram();
  m_shaders[0] = createShader(loadShader(filename + ".vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  m_shaders[1] = createShader(loadShader(filename +".fs"),   GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++ ){
      glAttachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
  }

  glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 0, "position");

  glLinkProgram(m_program);
  checkShaderError(m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "Error: Program failed to   link!");

  glValidateProgram(m_program);
  checkShaderError(m_program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, true, "Error: Program is invalid!");
}

Shader::~Shader(){
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
  {
    glDetachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
    glDeleteShader(m_shaders[i]);
  }
  glDeleteProgram(m_program);
}

static std::string loadShader(const std::string& filename){

  std::ifstream file;
  file.open((filename).c_str());

  std::string output;
  std::string line;

  if(file.is_open()){
      while(file.good()){
          getline(file, line);
          output.append(line + "\n");
      }
  }else{
      std::cerr << "Shader could not be loaded, shader id: " << filename <<       std::endl;
  }
  file.close();
  return output;
}
```

Comment: what is the filename and what is the actual file path?

Comment: sorry, filename is basicShader.vs for the vertex shader and basicShader.fs for the fragment shader. I've tried putting them in a res folder, in the working directory, in the product directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Completely rebuild the project and try to run it again.

EDIT: Changing filepaths in code has a strange behaviour. I personally always have to rebuild the file to fix this.

Comment: where did you end up placing the files?

Comment: I guess my filepath was "\\resources\\shaders\\XYZ.vs" so it was in the working directory -> resources -> shaders

Comment: Well that seems to have solved the problem. Thanks so much.